# Creating an IF statement for datagrid value

Tags: c#, datagrid, if-statement

This is something I thought would be easier than it's turning out to be.  For whatever reason, I can't seem to figure out a way to make what I'm trying to do here work with an If statement:

```
  List<int> miscTimes = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < MISCdataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                if (MISCdataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == "Something")
                {
                    miscTimes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(MISCdataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
                }
            }
            return miscTimes;
```

For some reason, I can't get it to like anything I do with the if statement:

```
if (MISCdataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == "Something")
```

it doesn't throw an exception, but it's not building my list. It has the green underline and says "Possible unintended reference comparison; cast the left side type to 'string'" 
  I've tried converting to string and all of that.  How should I go about this?

Comment: suppose I should've been more descriptive.  It doesn't throw an exception, but it's not building my list.  It has the green underline and says "Possible unintended reference comparison; cast the left side type to 'string'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataGridViewCell.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) property is of type [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) and therefore you have to cast to [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)

```
(String)dataGridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == "Something"
```

or rely on [`Object.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx).

```
Object.Equals(dataGridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value, "Something")
```

Using `Object.Equals()` is more robust because it can deal with the value not being of type `String`. On the other hand using the cast emphasizes the fact that the value must be a `String` and will throw an exception if it is not - clearly showing that you probably have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` property is of type `Object`.
Therefore, you're using the standard `==` operator, which compares objects by reference.

To compare strings correctly, you need to compare them by value.  (Because you can have two different `String` instances holding the same value)

Change it to

```
if ((string)MISCdataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == "Something")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Value" returns an object, and you are comparing against a string, so it is comparing references, when you probably want to compare the value, i.e., "Something".  Cast the left side to a string (or call ToString(), whatever, just make sure that you are explicitly comparing two strings).